# Unknown characters before String filename list in android application

Tags: java, android, writefile

I've saved an array list in the android mobile storage with a .txt extension. The problem is that there are unknown characters (as it's shown in the screenshot) coming before each file name that my string does not contain these characters.

```
  if (uri != null)
                file = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");

            if (file != null) {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        file.getFileDescriptor());

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {

                    out.writeObject(removeAccents(myList.get(i).getName() +"\n"));
                }


//                out.flush();
                out.close();

                fileOutputStream.close();
                file.close();
```

and the screenshot is: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Do not use ObjectOutputStream. Just write to the file output stream.

Comment: It is unclear how you display the file. Which app is used?

Comment: @blackapps I'm developing this application

Comment: Then you should show the code that reads and displays the file. And if you used object output stream for writing then you have to use object input stream for reading.

Comment: @blackapps I try it. but not working. Same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ObjectOutputStream, I should use OutputStreamWriter.